# GREP "--prefix" as a pattern

Tags: grep

When I use `grep -nrF '--prefix' *` I get `unrecognized option --prefix`.

Is there any way to find this speical chracter such as `--` using grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Cartman**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520895/grep-prefix-as-a-pattern/15520950#15520950) is right that the general way is to use `--` but a `grep` specific solution is to use `-e`:

```
grep -nrFe '--prefix' *
```

From `man grep`:

> ```
> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
> ```
>
> Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, **or to protect a pattern beginning with  a 
>   hyphen**
>                 **(-).**  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `--` to tell grep that the rest is not a command line option

```
grep -nrF -- '--prefix' *
```